# Unable to open deployment assembly option in Rational Application Developer 8.0.4

Tags: rad

I'm using RAD 8.0.4 version. After installing plugins like SVN, Maven and PMD, when I try to open 'Deployment Assembly' option for any EAR project(right click->properties->deployment assembly) its showing that "The currently displayed page contains invalid values".

Can anyone help me out to solve this..??

Comment: Look at the workspace's log file, under `.metadata/.log`, and paste some relevant information here please.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue, and the log in .metadata/log like this:

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2012-11-23 11:37:45.031
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/eclipse/jst/j2ee/componentcore/J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getDefaultDeploymentDescriptorFolder(Lorg/eclipse/wst/common/componentcore/resources/IVirtualFolder;)Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IPath;

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  It was because I didn't have all projects being referenced, in my workspace.  To fix the issue, I had to remove the references.  To do that, I had to open the referenced projects first, then open the deployment assembly, and remove the reference.